# Calculating monthly returns from daily prices in R

Tags: r, xts, quantmod

I have a data set that's arranged like this:

```
    NO0003659914 NO0003106700 NO0010014632 NO0003095309 NO0003666604 NO0003101404 NO0003679102 X        
2015-12-21 "25"         "1,85"       "12"         "0,3"        "132,5"      "10,255"     "48"         "3544,4" 
2015-12-22 "25"         "1,89"       "11,8"       "0,29"       "132,5"      "10,255"     "50"         "3564,46"
2015-12-23 "25"         "1,8"        "11,95"      "0,4"        "132,5"      "10,255"     "56,25"      "3612,8" 
2015-12-28 "25"         "1,69"       "12,7"       "0,34"       "132,5"      "10,255"     "53"         "3608,38"
2015-12-29 "25"         "1,58"       "13,3"       "0,36"       "132,5"      "10,255"     "56"         "3606,44"
2015-12-30 "25"         "1,61"       "12,9"       "0,34"       "132,5"      "10,255"     "56"         "3622,9"
```

And it is a xts object:

```
> class(tdata)
[1] "xts" "zoo"
```

I want to turn these daily observations into monthly returns, and have tried to do so using a for loop.

```
symbols <- colnames(tdata)

for(symbol in symbols) {
  tdata <- get(symbol)
  tdata <- to.monthly(tdata,indexAt='lastof',drop.time=TRUE)
  indexFormat(tdata) <- '%d.%m.%Y'
  colnames(tdata) <- gsub("tdata",symbol,colnames(tdata))
  assign(symbol,tdata)
}
```

I have also tried with `quantmod::monthlyReturn(x = tdata, subset = tdata$row.names)`, but then I get:

> Error in na.omit.xts(x) : unsupported type

Is this error because I have NA values in my time series? Any help on how to easily convert these into monthly returns? Been struggling some time now, and any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Your data appear to be character, not numeric, because whatever raw data source you imported from used a `","` as a decimal separator instead of the default of `"."`. Once your data are in a numeric format, you could use a combination of `xts::endpoints` and `TTR::ROC` to calculate returns for a specific periodicity.

```
Lines <- 'Index NO0003659914 NO0003106700 NO0010014632 NO0003095309 NO0003666604 NO0003101404 NO0003679102 X        
2015-12-21 "25"         "1,85"       "12"         "0,3"        "132,5"      "10,255"     "48"         "3544,4" 
2015-12-22 "25"         "1,89"       "11,8"       "0,29"       "132,5"      "10,255"     "50"         "3564,46"
2015-12-23 "25"         "1,8"        "11,95"      "0,4"        "132,5"      "10,255"     "56,25"      "3612,8" 
2015-12-28 "25"         "1,69"       "12,7"       "0,34"       "132,5"      "10,255"     "53"         "3608,38"
2015-12-29 "25"         "1,58"       "13,3"       "0,36"       "132,5"      "10,255"     "56"         "3606,44"
2015-12-30 "25"         "1,61"       "12,9"       "0,34"       "132,5"      "10,255"     "56"         "3622,9"'
tdata <- as.xts(read.zoo(text=Lines, header=TRUE, dec=","))
TTR::ROC(tdata[endpoints(tdata,'weeks')])
```

Comment: Thank you! This worked as a charm!
Only thing i doesnt understand is why you include the TTR::? I tried the formula without it and it seems to do the same thing with or without it. What is it supposed to add to the formula?

Comment: @Alfemann: I just added it for reference, so other readers would know where the function is located. If you have quantmod loaded+attached, TTR will also be loaded+attached, so you can omit the `TTR::` and just call `ROC`.

Comment: Thanks a lot! This was to great help :)